# Workflow Manager 1.0 CU installation fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

we ran the install for workflow manager 1.0 from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35375)

We get errors when tying to run the cumulative update for [Workflow Manager 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42036)

3 servers: SQL, Application and WFE
SharePoint 2013 Enterprise
Installation of WFMgr 1.0 on WFE

Are we missing some step here? 
the CU's for WFMgr and Service Bus just don't seem to run.
See setup.log below:

setup.log:

```
[03/12/14 13:26:09] Performing install.
[03/12/14 13:26:09] At least one of the product packages has been detected.
[03/12/14 13:26:09] preReqUpdateDisplayName is : 
[03/12/14 13:26:09] 
[03/12/14 13:26:09] Wizard mode on.
The following products will be enhanced:
Workflow Manager 1.0
Attempting to open cached Msi package for product code: {04A7199E-565D-4654-88A3-80A9A7BADDD9}
Successfully opened cached Msi package.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Opening Service Control Manager...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying files...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Checking and creating target directory C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall2902007.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Package Workflow Manager 1.0 is installed.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file AppServerV1-WorkflowManagerpatch30.msp ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file AppServerV1-WorkflowManagerpatch30.msp ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file TargetWFVersion.txt ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file UnifiedWFHotfixUpgrade.PS1 ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file RemoveFile.PS1 ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file Setup.xml ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Copying file Setup.exe ...
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Package Workflow Manager 1.0 is installed.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Package code is {04A7199E-565D-4654-88A3-80A9A7BADDD9}.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Executing preinstall custom actions. 1 actions to execute.
[03/12/14 13:26:18] Starting process "C:\Windows\system32\..\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File UnifiedWFHotfixUpgrade.PS1 -HotfixType "S" -PackageType "server" -opcode "PatchBefore" -platform "x64" ...
[03/12/14 13:26:19] Process exit code is -1.
get-itemproperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Service Bus\1.0' 
because it does not exist.
At C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers 
Updates\Updates\Uninstall2902007\UnifiedWFHotfixUpgrade.PS1:972 char:21
+   $sbinstallpath = (get-itemproperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Service 
Bus\1.0"  ...
+                     
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Servic 
   e Bus\1.0:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetIt 
   emPropertyCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers 
Updates\Updates\Uninstall2902007\UnifiedWFHotfixUpgrade.PS1:973 char:3
+   $sbinstallpath = $sbinstallpath.TrimEnd('\')
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


[03/12/14 13:26:19] Deleting file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall2902007\EBizTemp.txt ...
[03/12/14 13:26:19] Operation succeeded.
[03/12/14 13:26:19] The custom action returned -1.
[03/12/14 13:26:19] One of the custom actions failed. The installation cannot continue. See log for details.
```

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

1st question, after the installation of WF manager, did you test if it was working?

For CU there are pre-req

Software requirements:

- PowerShell 3.0 must be installed on the computer to be updated.
  PowerShell 3.0 is included in the Windows Management Framework 3.0
  installation. Go to Windows Management Framework 3.0 to install this
  update.
- Workflow Manager Client 1.0 must be installed on the computer.
- For computers that have Workflow Manager 1.0 installed, the following
  additional requirements apply:

  1. The Service Bus for Windows Server cumulative update must be
     installed on the whole   computer farm before you install the
     cumulative update for Workflow Manager 1.0
  2. [2799752](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799752) Description of the Service Bus for Windows Server Cumulative
     Update: February 22, 2013

also Service Bus for Windows Server must be installed on the computer.

Comment: Response: 1st question: WF manager is installed but not yet configured because we need to create the certificate and allow SSL on the SQL.

Comment: Response: 2nd part: PowerShell is installed. According to the Web Platform Installer 4.6, Workflow manager client 1.0 Refresh and Workflow Manager CU2 to get to 1.0 refresh and Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 are all installed. I see in the Web Platform Installer 4.6 the option to install "Service Bus 1.0" and "Service Bus 1.0 Cumulative Update 1". Should these two be installed instead of the Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1?